# Copy Content Elements in TYPO3 v6.1

Tags: typo3

in TYPO3 before version 6.1 it's possible to copy Content-Elements. Click on the small icon from the Contentelemet -> show small menu, there you can copy, crop, delete ...

BUT since TYPO3 version 6.1. there's no menu any more if you'll click on the small CE-Icon.

Is this a bug or a feature? ;)

Comment: In 6.1.1 it is working to click on the icon in the left upper corner of the content element. So generally it works.

Comment: I click on that small icon, but nothing happens. I know the icon and normally there's a contect menu, if I click on it. Bit not in my version of 6.1.1 - The wrong pageconfig.ts? Is there my error?

Comment: I've made a new TYPO3 Installation version 6.1.1  and it works  - it must be my pageconfig.ts

Comment: on my console I found this: "Folder tt_content does not exist", if I click on that small icon (CE)

Answer (score 0):

The reason must be fedext.net - extension! I locate the problem.